# Bootstrap 3 Grid System distortion

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need help with the Bootstrap Grid system (col-md , col-sm, col-lg, etc.)
My grid keeps on getting distorted when the screen is a smaller resolution. All these resolutions are from desktops and laptops, no tablets/mobile phones.

I know that col-sm is for resolutions up to 750px, and col-d is up to 970px.
Shouldn't that cover the tested resolutions?

Here is are examples.

Resolution: 1280x1024
Everything looks the way it's supposed to.

[1280x1024](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qb2ry.png)

Resolution:  1024x600
Labels and inputs are misaligned and distorted.

Looks the same as Inline Method

HTML:

```
    <div class="panel-group">
<div class="panel">  
    <div class="panel-body">        
        <div class="row col-sm-12 col-md-12">               
            <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 verticalline">                            
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 control-label">
                        Cust PO #
                    </label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-8">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control textlabellook" id="custpotxt" name="custpotxt" value=""/>                            
                    </div>
                </div>                          
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                        <p class="middle"><b>Customer License Contact Info</b></p>
                    </div>
                </div>   
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 control-label">
                        Cust Name
                    </label>
                    <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8">
                         <p class="form-control-static"><input type="text" class="form-control textlabellook" id="suppnametxt" name="suppnametxt" placeholder="Name..." value="" /></p>
                    </div>
                </div> 
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-xs-4 col-sm-5 col-md-5 control-label">
                         Cust Phone #
                    </label>
                    <div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-7 col-md-7">
                         <p class="form-control-static"><input type="text" class="form-control textlabellook" id="suppphonetxt" placeholder="Phone #..." name="suppphonetxt" value="" onkeypress="return numbersonly(event, false)"/></p>
                    </div>
                </div> 
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 control-label">
                         Cust Email
                    </label>
                    <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8">
                         <p class="form-control-static"><input type="text" class="form-control textlabellook email" id="suppemailtxt" name="suppemailtxt" placeholder="Email..." value="" /></p>
                    </div>
                </div> 
            </div               
            <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 verticalline">
                <!-- stuff in here -->
            </div>                               
            <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 verticalline"> 
                <!-- stuff in here -->                                             
            </div>                  
            <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">  
                <!-- stuff in here -->
            </div>              
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

[Tested with Inline method provided by vanburenx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWnqh.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `columns` and `rows` mixed together line, columns go inside of `rows`. And you don't need so the all those columns that are basically duplicates See [docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) and example.

**UPDATE**

You can nest your columns/rows in order to line all your inputs/display items yup across a screen. See [Nesting Forms](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting)

I've put two versions: One with inline labels and one without.

**See working examples below.**

```css
/**FORM 1 INLINE LABEL**/

#theForm,
#theForm2 {
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #266080;
}
.no-gutter >[class*='col-'] {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.middle {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.black {
  border-bottom: 6px solid black;
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .red {
    border-bottom: 6px solid red;
    margin: 10px 0;
  }
}
/**FORM 2 BLOCK LABEL**/

.no-gutter2 >[class*='col-'] {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-top: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}
.middle {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.blue {
  border-bottom: 3px solid lightblue;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<hr>
<form id="theForm">
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Inline Label Nested Form</h2>
    <div class="row black">
      <!-- START CONTAINER-->
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label">Cust PO #</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-8">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control textlabellook" name="custpotxt" value="" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="form-group">
              <p class="middle text-center"><b>Customer License Contact Info</b> 
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label">Cust PO #</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-8">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control textlabellook" name="custpotxt" value="" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label">Cust PO #</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-8">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control textlabellook" name="custpotxt" value="" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label">Cust PO #</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-8">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control textlabellook" name="custpotxt" value="" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- END CONTAINER-->
      <div class="red"></div>
      <!-- START CONTAINER-->
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label">Cust PO #2</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-8">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control textlabellook" name="custpotxt" value="" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="form-group">
              <p class="middle text-center"><b>Customer License Contact Info</b> 
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label">Cust PO #</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-8">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control textlabellook" name="custpotxt" value="" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label">Cust PO #</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-8">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control textlabellook" name="custpotxt" value="" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label">Cust PO #</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-8">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control textlabellook" name="custpotxt" value="" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- END CONTAINER-->
      <div class="red"></div>
      <!-- START CONTAINER-->
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label">Cust PO #3</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-8">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control textlabellook" name="custpotxt" value="" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="form-group">
              <p class="middle text-center"><b>Customer License Contact Info</b> 
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label">Cust PO #</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-8">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control textlabellook" name="custpotxt" value="" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label">Cust PO #</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-8">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control textlabellook" name="custpotxt" value="" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label">Cust PO #</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-8">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control textlabellook" name="custpotxt" value="" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- END CONTAINER-->
      <div class="red"></div>
      <!-- START CONTAINER-->
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label">Cust PO #4</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-8">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control textlabellook" name="custpotxt" value="" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="form-group">
              <p class="middle text-center"><b>Customer License Contact Info</b> 
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label">Cust PO #</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-8">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control textlabellook" name="custpotxt" value="" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label">Cust PO #</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-8">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control textlabellook" name="custpotxt" value="" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label">Cust PO #</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-8">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control textlabellook" name="custpotxt" value="" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- END CONTAINER-->
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
<hr>
<form id="theForm2">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <h2>Block Label Nested Form</h2>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="row no-gutter2 blue">
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <label class="control-label">Cust PO #</label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <input type="text" class="form-control textlabellook" name="custpotxt" value="" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <p class="middle"><b>Customer License Contact Info</b> 
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <label class="control-label">Cust PO #</label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <input type="text" class="form-control textlabellook" name="custpotxt" value="" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <label class="control-label">Cust PO #</label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <input type="text" class="form-control textlabellook" name="custpotxt" value="" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <label class="control-label">Cust PO #</label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <input type="text" class="form-control textlabellook" name="custpotxt" value="" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <p class="middle"><b>Attach POs to Order</b> 
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="row no-gutter2 blue">
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <label class="control-label">Cust PO #</label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <input type="text" class="form-control textlabellook" name="custpotxt" value="" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <p class="middle"><b>Customer License Contact Info</b> 
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <label class="control-label">Cust PO #</label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <input type="text" class="form-control textlabellook" name="custpotxt" value="" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <label class="control-label">Cust PO #</label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <input type="text" class="form-control textlabellook" name="custpotxt" value="" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <label class="control-label">Cust PO #</label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <input type="text" class="form-control textlabellook" name="custpotxt" value="" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <p class="middle"><b>Attach POs to Order</b> 
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="row no-gutter2 blue">
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <label class="control-label">Cust PO #</label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <input type="text" class="form-control textlabellook" name="custpotxt" value="" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <p class="middle"><b>Customer License Contact Info</b> 
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <label class="control-label">Cust PO #</label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <input type="text" class="form-control textlabellook" name="custpotxt" value="" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <label class="control-label">Cust PO #</label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <input type="text" class="form-control textlabellook" name="custpotxt" value="" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <label class="control-label">Cust PO #</label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <input type="text" class="form-control textlabellook" name="custpotxt" value="" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <p class="middle"><b>Attach POs to Order</b> 
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div class="row no-gutter2 blue">
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <label class="control-label">Cust PO #</label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <input type="text" class="form-control textlabellook" name="custpotxt" value="" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <p class="middle"><b>Customer License Contact Info</b> 
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <label class="control-label">Cust PO #</label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <input type="text" class="form-control textlabellook" name="custpotxt" value="" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <label class="control-label">Cust PO #</label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <input type="text" class="form-control textlabellook" name="custpotxt" value="" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <label class="control-label">Cust PO #</label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <input type="text" class="form-control textlabellook" name="custpotxt" value="" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <p class="middle"><b>Attach POs to Order</b> 
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I have removed the "col-*" from the row div. I am trying to make a single row have 4 sections, hence my "col-sm-3" below the row instead of your "col-sm-12". The 12 works perfectly in both resolutions but the 3 still gives problems even after removing the cols from the row div and change all cols to "xs".

Comment: See the updated answer (Use full page option on Snippet).

Comment: The block method works for both resolutions is not the format i'm looking for. The inline still gives problems, see the image in the OP. I copy pasta'd your inline code and thats what it gives me.

Comment: Then you either have other rules over riding the defaults or you've missed something: as you can see if you go to "Run code snippet" above and use Full page, it does not show those same results as you have in your image.

Comment: Yeah, I think it's the css styling from the theme i'm using. Will probably have to dig deeper. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the offending line.

```
class="col-xs-4 col-sm-5 col-md-5 control-label"
```

Perhaps try setting it to:

```
class="col-xs-5 col-sm-5 col-md-5 control-label"
```

and see if that helps...

It's the only one that deviates from the others. Bootstrap is mobile first, and as such it's designed so that its classes work from the smallest up. So if you set:

```
  class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8">
```

It's the same as setting it to:

```
 class="col-xs-8">
```

Unless you're gonna change the larger layouts, just the the smallest one and they'll all inherit upwards.

Comment: I have made the changes and used just "col-xs-8" but still still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following inline css for the row. It will help the distorted column reallign each others.

```
<div class="row" style="display:flex; flex-wrap:wrap;">
...
</div>
```

Hope this helps.